# Integrating Salesforce CRM to Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, authentication, wsdl2apex

I Have a requirement to call Soap API of Exact target via a callout from my Salesforce CRM Apex class. I am using the WSDL2APex approach and i'm able to successfully make the call to exact target and receive the response when i pass the security tag with Usernametoken details.

However, due to some implicit requirements, I have a necessity to pass the fueloauth element instead of username and password in the soap envelop.

Below is the sample inner class i have for the header. However, it is adding an additional wrapper `<Header>` which I am not able to figure out how to remove. Need some help here.

```
 public class Header{
        public String fueloAuth;
        private String[] fueloAuth_type_info = new String[]{'fueloAuth','http://exacttarget.com','String','1','-','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'fueloAuth'};       
   }
```

code in my stub class is as below to add the header, where i have the webserviceCallout.invoke method.

```
  public ETPartnerAPI.Header Header;
  private String Header_hns = 'env:Header=www.exacttarget.com';
```

generated output is

```
<env:Header>
  <env:Header xmlns="www.exacttarget.com">
     <fueloAuth>somevalue</fueloAuth>
  </env:Header>
</env:Header>
```

What i'm looking at is

```
  <env:Header xmlns="www.exacttarget.com">
     <fueloAuth>somevalue</fueloAuth>
  </env:Header>
```

Comment: Have you look into using the Marketing Cloud Connector app in AppExchange?  Depending on your project goals, you may be able to use this app to couple Salesforce and the Marketing Cloud (aka ExactTarget), rather than writing custom apex.

Comment: Are you able to share the WSDL? One option would be to generate the corresponding HttpRequest. This could be modified as required.

Comment: @DavidDevoy , Thanks . Connector we are unable to use as it is a strict one to one environment mapping. one Instance of Salesforce connected to one instance of ET. We wanted to go with API since we could re-use the ET instance from multiple Salesforce org.

Comment: Yes, we are moving with construction of HttpRequest now  , though I wish the WSDL approach would have been much easier and easy to maintain.

Comment: https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is a simple string soap header isn't supported.

From [apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm)

> WSDLs that don’t use the document literal wrapped style. The following
>   WSDL snippet doesn’t use document literal wrapped style and results in
>   an “Unable to find complexType” error when imported.