# FuelOAuth node is missing in Marketing cloud WSDL

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, marketingcloudapi

Need help on Marketing cloud WSDL. I am not able to find the FueOAuth node in marketing cloud WSDL. I got the WSDL from below link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/wsdl-endpoint-links.htm

I want to include the fueloauth header into my soap request in APEX.

Can anybody help?

Comment: you can add manually that like this <fueloauth>accestoken</fueloauth>

Comment: <fueloauth> node is missing in my wsdl. There should be a proper fueloauth node in my wsdl so that i can assign my access token to fueloauth in APEX. I am not sure if i have missed anything while generating the wsdl.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example SOAP envelope header with fueloauth:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
<fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">ACCESS TOKEN</fueloauth>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Comment: I know we can directly use this header inside our soap request but I want to add this header in APEX using the marketing cloud  WSDL. So how to add this header into my soap request.

Comment: Try this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270974/apex-changes-in-exact-target-partner-wsdl-to-include-fueloauth-in-soap-envelo

Comment: Thanks for the link!!. But there is no such class named “fueloauth” in my apex generated class. Can you please tell me to add this class?